# Where can I ask a question about a SNES game?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about the Mega Man X game on SNES.

There are helmet enemies in every level and at the end of each level there appears a table with many helmet enemies and a number on each.

I want to know what the meaning of these helmet enemies is.

Comment: I would expect https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but they don't allow questions that are *Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone* but it looks like your question is of the category *Game mechanics and terminology* which seems on-topic.

Comment: I'll just answer: it's the password system. Before we had save states and battery backed memory, we had to manually copy down those numbers and re-enter them  at the beginning to get back to where we were.

Comment: related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319905/is-there-a-logic-to-the-megaman-x-password-screen/319906#319906

Comment: @dustytrash Excellent find!

Answer (score 5):

There's always [Arqade.SE](//gaming.stackexchange.com) for gameplay, mechanics, etc. This sounds close enough that I would try there first. If you purely need backstory, however, [SciFi and Fantasy](//scifi.stackexchange.com) might be better.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319905/is-there-a-logic-to-the-megaman-x-password-screen/319906#319906

Comment: Keep in mind that game *mechanics* questions (how to play the game) are off-topic on SciFi and Fantasy. Asking who made Mega Man's arm cannon is on-topic. Asking what button to push to fire it is not.